# unmanaged class method: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, multithreading, clr, unmanaged

I'd like to run, in a managed Thread, a method from a unmanaged class, and quickly got confused, being neophyte to CLR.

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class ManagedClass;

int main()
{
    ManagedClass^ managedObject = gcnew ManagedClass();

    Thread^ threadOk = gcnew Thread(
                         gcnew ThreadStart(
                           managedObject,
                           &ManagedClass::Run));


    boost::asio::io_service unmanagedObject;

    Thread^ threadWrong = gcnew Thread(
                            gcnew ThreadStart(
                              unmanagedObject,
                              &boost::asio::io_service::run));
}
```

Because, obviously,

> invalid delegate initializer -- function is not a member of a managed class

So I started googling about *Managed Threads on Unmanaged code* but found nothing clarifying. Any advice? Am I on the completely wrong way?

Comment: Any reason you can't call a managed function, which then calls your unmanaged function?

Answer (score 0):

As UKMonkey said, a little boilerplate was sufficient...

```
public ref class CMyStartService
{
    boost::asio::io_service * _pIoService;

public:
    CMyStartService(boost::asio::io_service * pIoService) :
        _pIoService(pIoService)
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        _pIoService->run();
    }
};

// in main

CMyStartService^ cMyStartService = gcnew CMyStartService(&ioService);
Thread^ thread_io_service = gcnew Thread( 
                              gcnew ThreadStart(
                                cMyStartService, &CMyStartService::run));
```